# When I reindex in Elastic Search I can't rename a field with a new name that contains a dash

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform a reindex and rename a field at the same time. I am using the _reindex API as suggested by the documentation. The problem is that when the new name of the field contains a dash the script fails:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.new-name= ctx._source.remove(\"oldname\")"
  }
}
```

"newname" works "new-name" doesn't. I have also tried "new-name" but dosn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash will be intepreted as minus by painless. In order to prevent this behaviour, just use the following notation:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "source":"if(ctx._source['oldname'] != null){ctx._source['new-name'] = ctx._source['oldname'];ctx._source.remove("oldname")}";
  }
}
```

One could also create an ingest pipeline and use the [rename processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rename-processor.html).

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/rename_oldfield_to_newfield
{
  "description" : "rename oldfield to newfield",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "rename" : {
        "field": "oldfield ",
        "target_field": "new-field",
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure" : true
      },
      "on_failure" : [
        {
          "set" : {
            "field" : "error.message",
            "value" : "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the pipeline for [reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-with-an-ingest-pipeline) is pretty straight forward:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex",
    "pipeline": "rename_oldfield_to_newfield"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the first script is correct. Field names must be surrounded by square brackets. But what do you mean with "interpreted by painless"? :) Just a curiosity :)

Comment: it´s just a minus sign. painless tries to calculate the result of "new" -(minus) "name" and fails :)